# MSAL.NET OBO refresh token problems

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement an OBO flow through to the graph API on a middle-tier API (.NET 5.0) using MSAL.NET. I'm running into two frustrating problems, and I can't find anyone having similar problems, so I think I'm misunderstanding something!

Problem 1: Whenever I call MSAL's GetAccountAsync, it always returns null when there should be an account loaded.

Problem 2: Whenever I call MSAL's AcquireTokenSilent, I always get the error "No refresh token found in the cache." even though I got one.

Here's what I have:

Once the web app authenticates, it passes through the token to a graph auth endpoint on the API:

```
            var authenticationResult = await ClaimHelper.ClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(GraphHelpers.BasicGraphScopes, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();

            var apiUserSession = await CouncilWiseAPIHelper.APIClient.Graph.AuthoriseUserAsync(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
```

which seems to work fine, and passes through a JWT to the API auth endpoint. The API implements an MSAL Confidential Client application and uses the SetBeforeAccess/SetAfterAccess token cache methods to save the cache to a database.

```
         _msalClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_graphConfig.ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
            .WithClientSecret(_graphConfig.ClientSecret)
            .Build();

        SetSerialiser(serialiser);
```

```
        public void SetSerialiser(MSALTokenCacheSerialiser serialiser)
        {
            _msalClient.UserTokenCache.SetBeforeAccessAsync(serialiser.BeforeAccessCallbackAsync);
            _msalClient.UserTokenCache.SetAfterAccessAsync(serialiser.AfterAccessCallbackAsync);
        }
```

And the serialiser methods look like this:

```
public async Task BeforeAccessCallbackAsync(TokenCacheNotificationArgs notification)
        {
            GraphUserTokenCache tokenCache = await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.GetByUserIdentifier(notification.SuggestedCacheKey);
            if (tokenCache == null)
            {
                tokenCache = await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.Get(notification.SuggestedCacheKey);
            }

            if (tokenCache != null)
            {
                notification.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(tokenCache.Value);
            }
        }

        public async Task AfterAccessCallbackAsync(TokenCacheNotificationArgs notification)
        {
            if (!notification.HasTokens)
            {
                // Delete from the cache
                await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.Delete(notification.SuggestedCacheKey);
            }

            if (!notification.HasStateChanged)
            {
                return;
            }
            GraphUserTokenCache tokenCache;
            if (notification.SuggestedCacheKey == notification.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier)
            {
                tokenCache = await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.GetByUserIdentifier(notification.SuggestedCacheKey);
            }
            else
            {
                tokenCache = await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.Get(notification.SuggestedCacheKey);
            }
            if (tokenCache == null)
            {
                var cache = notification.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
                tokenCache = new GraphUserTokenCache
                {
                    Id = notification.SuggestedCacheKey,
                    AccountIdentifier = notification.Account.HomeAccountId.ToString(),
                    Value = cache
                };

                await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.Add(tokenCache);
            }
            else
            {
                await _graphUserTokenCacheRepository.Update(tokenCache.Id, notification.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3());
            }
        }
```

I can see the token BeforeAccess and AfterAccess methods being called, and I can see the caches being created in the database (encryption has been removed while I'm trying to track down this issue). If I inspect the serialised token cache being saved, it NEVER has a refresh token populated, but if I inspect the requests with fiddler I can see a refresh token was indeed provided.
Finally, here is the code for retrieving the access token which is called whenever a graph request is made:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAccessToken(string accountId, string jwtBearerToken)
        {
            try
            {
                IAccount account = null;
                if (accountId.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    account = await _msalClient.GetAccountAsync(accountId);
                }

                var scope = _graphConfig.Scopes.Split(' ');

                if (account == null)
                {
                    var result = await _msalClient.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scope,
                        new UserAssertion(jwtBearerToken))
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = await _msalClient.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, account)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (MsalClientException ex)
            {
                ex.CwApiLog();
                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.CwApiLog();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

When it's called with the jwtBearerToken, it will successfully call `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf()` and the token is cached and a result returned, but when I come back to retrieve the account via `GetAccountAsync()` it always returns null even though I can see the token cache was loaded in `BeforeAccessCallbackAsync()`.

Also, even if I call `AcquireTokenSilent()` immediately after acquiring the obo token with the account it just returned, I will get an exception saying there is no refresh token in the cache.

I am totally lost on what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I never got this to work. I ended up reworking my approach and using Identity.Web to handle it for me which required some pretty major rejigging of code which was already using an IDistributedCache. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki#web-api-samples

I now have a pretty similar problem with a new webjob worker that I want to use the token cache. I will respond with an answer if I figure that out.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I had to use the rest api’s instead of the SDK thing,  I still used the SDK for the initial user consent on the client side, but the rest Apis for the token refresh.  Can send code if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem while running a long runing OBO flow, MSAL has recently implemented an interface `ILongRunningWebApi` for these use cases you can go and see this [new documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of#long-running-obo-processes)

Here is an extract:

> One OBO scenario is when a web API runs long running processes on
> behalf of the user (for example, OneDrive which creates albums for
> you). Starting with MSAL.NET 4.38.0, this can be implemented as such:
>
> Before you start a long running process, call:
>
> ```
> string sessionKey = // custom key or null
> var authResult = await ((ILongRunningWebApi)confidentialClientApp)
>          .InitiateLongRunningProcessInWebApi(
>               scopes,
>               userToken,
>               ref sessionKey)
>          .ExecuteAsync();
> ```
>
> userToken is a user token used to call this web API. sessionKey will
> be used as a key when caching and retrieving the OBO token. If set to
> null, MSAL will set it to the assertion hash of the passed-in user
> token. It can also be set by the developer to something that
> identifies a specific user session, like the optional sid claim from
> the user token (for more information, see Provide optional claims to
> your app). If the cache already contains a valid OBO token with this
> sessionKey, InitiateLongRunningProcessInWebApi will return it.
> Otherwise, the user token will be used to acquire a new OBO token from
> AAD, which will then be cached and returned.
>
> In the long-running process, whenever OBO token is needed, call:
>
> ```
> var authResult = await ((ILongRunningWebApi)confidentialClientApp)
>          .AcquireTokenInLongRunningProcess(
>               scopes,
>               sessionKey)
>          .ExecuteAsync();
> ```
>
> Pass the sessionKey which is associated with the current user's
> session and will be used to retrieve the related OBO token. If the
> token is expired, MSAL will use the cached refresh token to acquire a
> new OBO access token from AAD and cache it. If no token is found with
> this sessionKey, MSAL will throw a MsalClientException. Make sure to
> call InitiateLongRunningProcessInWebApi first.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm finally back onto this project so I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: I think this method will work, but I have a problem at the moment with the userToken these methods require. From what I gather this is the JWT token for logging in the user and is required. Problem is, in a background worker, we don't have access to this token and if I save it somewhere when the user logs into the API, it will likely be expired when the background worker wants it (for example, it runs a triggered job early in the morning). Do you have any ideas about this, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Indeed the user token is a JWT. It is only required for the initiating call. I guess if you do this call as soon as possible your cache sill be setup and the refresh token will be available later on. I don't have much more experience on this subject and I am dabbling a bit so I am sorry if I can't bring you a much more detailed answer. Just be sure that your session key is saved and accessible.

Comment: @myotherusernameisbetter Did this help solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The AcquireTokenInLongRunningProcess() call will work, but only while the token in the cache is valid. As soon as it expires, I get the same old no refresh token found in the cache.

Comment: If you do AcquireTokenInLongRunningProcess() in a try block and in your catch you call InitiateLongRunningProcessInWebApi would that work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - it looks as though the middleware (or the distributed cache itself) deletes the token cache entry when it finds it is expired.